# Keeping the TreeView and the Nodes separate

Tags: design-patterns

I have a problem concerning good application design that has been keeping me up for days now. One can describe it as:

- I have a tree structure made up of Nodes holding references to their children.
- I would now like to display that structure in a TreeView (I am the one who will implement the TreeView).
- I don't want the Nodes to 'know' that there is a TreeView, enabling me to keep those two components separate.

So where do I store the information whether an node is expanded or not (this information is not part of the Node itself).

Any idea on how to implement this in a clean way?

Thanks,
Konne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a TreeViewModal class that binds the view and the actual modal. Apparently this is known as [Model/View/ViewModel pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx). [Here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx) for the TreeView. Both the links has code in C# but it is easy to port to any language.

Comment: Do I understand corretly, that they just create an internal duplicate of the tree, similar to what David Harkness suggested in his comment?

Answer (score 0):

If each node has a unique hashable key you could add a hash table to `TreeView` to contain the keys of the expanded nodes.

Comment: Well I thought of that but it just seems extremely inefficient. Another concern is that I'm requiring the user to know about implementation details of my tree (they need to implement the hash_function or <)

Comment: You could build a parallel tree that is managed by `TreeView` where each node points to the respective `Node`, but that's even more overhead. If you want to keep the structures separated, you'll need to have some way for one structure to reference nodes in the other.